# Why does querying "green bay" not work when "green" or "bay" does in my Django view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Here is my view:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            q = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
            s_or_l = request.GET.get('s_or_l', None)
            p_class = request.GET.get('p_class', None)
            if p_class:
                posts = Listing.objects.filter(title__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l,
                                               property_class=p_class) | \
                        Listing.objects.filter(street_address__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l,
                                               property_class=p_class) | \
                        Listing.objects.filter(city__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l,
                                               property_class=p_class) | \
                        Listing.objects.filter(state__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l,
                                               property_class=p_class)
            else:
                posts = Listing.objects.filter(title__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l) | \
                        Listing.objects.filter(street_address__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l) | \
                        Listing.objects.filter(city__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l) | \
                        Listing.objects.filter(state__contains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l)
            return render(request, 'search/results.html', {'posts': posts, 'q': q})
        except KeyError:
            return redirect('home')
```

For a property with a `city` set to "Green Bay" the following searches work as intended:

`green`

`bay`

`Green Bay`

but `green bay` <-- does not work. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Why is it only case sensitive when there is a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `icontains` instead of `contains` for case insensistive search

```
Listing.objects.filter(city__icontains=q, is_live=1, sale_or_lease=s_or_l)
```

As to why `green` or `bay` or `Green Bay` works, but not `green bay`, i think the individual terms `green` and `bay` come somewhere else in lowercase maybe in your title or street address.

Filtering with `contains` for `green` or `bay` should in no way return `Green Bay` unless you use `icontains`